# Using SUBSTR and INSTR to get the suffix of a Name

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to get a suffix out of a last name. For example, I may get last names with suffix like this: *Smith Jr* or *Smith Jr*. or *Smith LCSW*, or *Smith J.A.C.G.*, or even something like this: Abardo Torres Jr or Abbas Feinberg LCSW, etc.

I know I have to use SUBSTR and INSTR, but I'm stuck. I can only do the following and can't make it work. Can anyone help me?

```
subtr(last_name,instr(last_name,' ',1) + 1
     ,(instr(last_name,' ', instr(last_name,' ',1)+1 - (instr(last_name,' ',1)+1)
```

Even if I can make it works it may only works for last name that consist of 1 word + suffix such as *Smith Jr* but will not work for last name that consist of 2 words such as *Abardo Torres Jr*

Comment: What about _Smith III PhD_? What do you expect.

Comment: Or if you're in the UK the following is possible (though highly unlikely): Field Marshal The Lord John of BlahBlah Esq KBE PhD MSc BSc etc. Name parsing is an extremely complex business. You won't come up with every possible suffix, think about all the professional and religious ones as well as academic. What sort of accuracy are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  last_name,
  regexp_replace(last_name, '\s*((Esq|KBE|MSc|BSc|Jr|LCSW|PhD|J\.A\.C\.G)\.?\s*)*$') 
    as name_without_suffix,
  regexp_substr(last_name, '((Esq|KBE|MSc|BSc|Jr|LCSW|PhD|J\.A\.C\.G)\.?\s*)*$') 
    as suffix
from your_table
```

---

To simply get the last word in a string:

```
regexp_substr(string, '(\S+)\s*$', 1, 1, 'i', 1)
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7c562/2)

Comment: Hi! Your statement return all last_names whether or not they have suffix. Those with suffix are stripped and return the last_name. What I need is to query last_name so I get all the suffixes back from those name that has suffix. The purpose I'm trying to do here is to get the suffix back so I can check if those are the right suffixes. For example, if I have last_name such as Forbe rj my statement should return the rj back so I know this is wrong and should update rj into Jr.

Comment: @user1557856 - How would you determine is `rj` part of last name or is a suffix?

Comment: Thank you for adding my examples but (for the UK again) you don't have BA, MA, MSci, MMath, MChem, MPhys, MPhil, CIMA, ACCA, RCN, AAT ABTA, BDS, FDS, RCS, FRCS, LLB... I could go on for literally ever... CMG, KCMG, QC, MD,... My point is, that a comprehensive, flexible, list is required. There's no other way to solve this problem.

Comment: I do have the list of suffixes in a table so I may be able to create a list from that table and then dynamically use the list to replace the Esq|KBE|MSc|BSc|Jr|LCSW|PhD|

Comment: @user1557856 - as I understood Ben's point, you should have list of suffixes AND list of misspelled suffixes (probably, generated automatically from the former list).